# Mui X Datagrid get dirty fields

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

Using Mui Datagrid v5 with  `experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}` enabled.
My use case is rather simple but i could not figure it out from the docs.

Given a table with one column i am trying to update all cells below the cell the user edited.

Initial Render:

| Id | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 3 | 50 |
| 4 | 50 |
| 5 | 50 |
| 6 | 50 |

**Now lets say user edits Amount in Row Id 3 from 50 to 60**

Desired Result:

| Id | Amount | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | Untouched |
| 2 | 50 | Untouched |
| 3 | 60 | Updated by user |
| 4 | 60 | Overwritten cause field was not dirty |
| 5 | 60 | Overwritten cause field was not dirty |
| 6 | 60 | Overwritten cause field was not dirty |

Basically i was expecting something like a dirty or touched state but i can't find it in the documentation.

---

**How do you know if a field is dirty in Mui X Datagrid?**

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. In v6 or with `experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}` enabled:

```
   <DataGrid
          experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
          editMode="row"
          processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
          ...
   />
```

Implementing isDirty

```
  const processRowUpdate = (newRow: typeof allRows[0], oldRow: typeof allRows[0]) => {   

    return  { ...newRow, isDirty: true } 
}
```

Using a valueGetter for the field

```
const columns: GridColDef<typeof allRows[0]>[] = [
...
{ 
 field: "amount",
 valueGetter: (params) => { 
    if (params.row.isDirty) {
      return params.row.amount
    } 
    // Field is not dirty, overwrite with a value 
    return Math.random() * 1000
  }
}
```